# assigning name on a specific character in a cell

Tags: excel-formula

i want to assign a name on a specific character in a cell
ex. Cell A1 is 123456HL78
 i want to name the 5th character in cell B1 as:
if 5 "Branch" 
if 6 "HO"
if 7 "franchise"

and the 6th character in cell C1 as:
if 6 "City"
if 7 "Province"
if 8 "Others"

therefore, result in B1=Branch and C1=City

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a lookup table and use `INDEX` and `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` if you prefer along with the `MID` function to return the 5th or 6th character from a text string and return a specific value based on that character.

```
In A1 123456HL78
In B1 =INDEX($E$1:$E$2,MATCH(MID($A$1,5,1),$D$1:$D$2))
In C1 =VLOOKUP(MID($A$1,6,1),$D$1:$E$4,2)
In D1 ="5" 'The = and quotes are important, without them Match and Vlookup cannot find a match and return a #value error.
In D2 ="6"
In E1 Branch
In E2 Province
```

You can obviously expand this however you like. Just note the hard coded 5 in the B1 `MID` function because you want the 5th character, as well as the 6 in C1.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two nested if formulas will work.

```
 In A1 123456HL78
 In B1 =IF(MID(A1,5,1) = "5","Branch",IF(MID(A1,5,1) = "6","HO",IF(MID(A1,5,1) = "7","Franchise","")))
 In C1 =IF(MID(A1,6,1) = "6","City",IF(MID(A1,6,1) = "7","Province",IF(MID(A1,6,1) = "8","Others","")))
```